# Object-oriented way to separate page-specific JavaScript in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

Assume I have a basic Rails app with three resources: `authors`, `blogs`, and `books`.  I created the resources with the `scaffold` command, so each resource has their own JavaScript file: `authors.js`, `blogs.js`, and `books.js`.

I saw a couple different implementations on how we can keep the global namespace clean for our JavaScript, as well as keep our page-specific JavaScript separate from each other so they don't clash.

Here is my devised implementation.  It appears to do what I want, but I wanted to get feedback if this would be considered a bad implementation/bad practice for some reason.  I would also welcome other implementations if people have a better way.

For all layouts within ***`app/views/layouts`*** specify this for the `body` tag:

```
<body class="<%= controller_name %>">
```

For the JavaScript code:  As we know, all JavaScript in Rails is eventually pulled together into one big JavaScript file.  For readability purposes here I pulled all the JavaScript from each of the separate JavaScript files and put them together (within the app I would keep the JavaScript code separate within each of their corresponding js files):

```
var authorsjs = {      
init: function(){
    alert("hello from authorjs");
    // all author bindings specified here
    $("#oneEl").on('click', function(){
        alert("oneEl was clicked");
    });
},
someAuthorFunc: function(){
    alert("someAuthorFunc run");
}
};

$(document).on('page:change', function(){
if($('body').hasClass("authors") == true ){
        authorsjs.init();
}
});


var booksjs = {      
init: function(){
    alert("init booksjs run");
    // all books bindings specified here
    $("#twoEl").on('click', function(){
        alert("twoEl was clicked");
    });
},
someBookFunc: function(){
    alert("someBookFunc run");
}
};

$(document).on('page:change', function(){
if($('body').hasClass("authors") == true ){
        authorsjs.init();
}
});
```

So as expected, these click events will not work for views associated to `blogs`, the event bound to `#oneEl` only works on views associated with authors, and the event bound to `#twoEl` only works on views associated with books.

Comment: You can get rid of calling `$(document).on('page:change', function(){})` which I think you are doing because of turbolink. You can use `jquery-turbolinks` gem to lessen the burden.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @charlietfl: I wanted to get feedback if this would be considered a bad implementation/bad practice for some reason. I would also welcome other implementations if people have a better way.

Comment: checking body class is common but placing your methods in global namespace seems like what you were wanting to avoid. Question is probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @charlietfl which methods are in the global namespace?  As I understand it, I encapsulated my methods within objects to prevent polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer based on feedback**

The following works.  I am using the jquery-turbolinks gem.  Each of the controller's js is encapsulated in an object.  For each page request the `body` class is checked and the appropriate object's `init` method is run.  I also went ahead and created a `someGlobals` object which provides common js code across all controllers.

This code works as intended but is quite messy.  I wish there was some way to clean up front-end code.  If you have any suggestions let me know:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var authorsjs = {      
        init: function(){
            alert("hello from authorjs");
            // all author bindings specified here
            $("#oneEl").on('click', function(){
                alert("oneEl was clicked");
            });
        },
        someAuthorFunc: function(){
            alert("someAuthorFunc run");
        }
    };

    if($('body').hasClass("authors") == true ){
        authorsjs.init();
    }
});


$(document).ready(function(){
        var booksjs = {      
        init: function(){
            alert("init booksjs run");
            // all books bindings specified here
            $("#twoEl").on('click', function(){
                alert("twoEl was clicked");
                booksjs.someBookFunc();
            });
        },
        someBookFunc: function(){
            alert("someBookFunc run");
        }
    };

    if($('body').hasClass("booksjs") == true ){
        booksjs.init();
    }
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    var blogsjs = {
        init: function(){
            blogsjs.formValidations();
        },
        formValidations: function(){
            $('#blog_title').on("click", function(){
                console.log($(this).val());
                $('p').css("color", "green");
                $(this).css("color", "blue");
                alert("hello");
            });
            $('#blog_title').on("keypress", function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
                $("#preview").text(value);
            });
        }

    };

    if($('body').hasClass("blogs") == true){
        blogsjs.init(); 
    }   
});



$(document).ready(function(){
    var someGlobals = {
        init: function(){
            $('p').on('click', function(){
                alert("Global: P was clicked somehwere!");
            })
        }

    };
    someGlobals.init();
});
```